# GPIO irq: Falling and Rising edge detection

Tags: arm, embedded, gpio, irq, omap

I try to create bare metal application for TI am335x soc based board. One thing I need to do is to invoke `callback1` on rising edge and `callback2` on falling edge. From the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73p/spruh73p.pdf) I figured out, that simultaneous detection for rising and falling edge could be enabled by writing `1 << pin` to RISINGDETECT and FALLINGDETECT GPIO registers. However, I can't understand (see no signs of it in datasheet), how could I determine if the currently appeared interrupt was caused by RISING edge on GPIO or by FALLING edge?

Comment: Check the state of the pin?  E.G. a rising edge results in a state of `on`.

Comment: Bingo, the question is really dumb. You can post it as an answer if you would like to. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how could I determine if the currently appeared interrupt was caused by RISING edge on GPIO or by FALLING edge?

Try checking the state of the pin.
A rising edge results in a `on` state, whereas a falling edge results in a `off` state.
So the current state of the pin implies the direction of the most-recent interrupt.