Wait for interrupt for specific level
Edit: the question below is description of the specific situation, which will be solved if answer for the following is found:
Driver needs to read the current state (value) of the GPIO set up as irq line - is it possible and how?

Edit 1: I have checked involved CPU datasheet, and the problem is deeper than I thought. PIO controller may simply not expose the current value if pin is configured as "functional pin", not as input or output. However it seems to be possible to change configuration of the interrupt function on the fly through the PIO registers.

This is Allwinner H3 datasheet, page 322.

When reading from the related device using its driver I may get interrupts triggered by the following conditions:
/*
 * IRQ_TYPE_NONE        - default, unspecified type
 * IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING     - rising edge triggered
 * IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING    - falling edge triggered
 * IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_BOTH       - rising and falling edge triggered
 * IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH      - high level triggered
 * IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW       - low level triggered
 * IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_MASK      - Mask to filter out the level bits
 * IRQ_TYPE_SENSE_MASK      - Mask for all the above bits
 * IRQ_TYPE_PROBE       - Special flag for probing in progress
 */

But I need to wait for specific level, e.g. sometimes I need the read() to block until line gets low, and sometimes until it gets high. Per documentation it seems these flags can not be changed on the fly, and opening GPIO pin for level read is not possible because it is busy with interrupt. Maybe it is possible to request/release interrupt each poll request, but that must be ugly.
In general algorithm if I need low level looks like (set up as level triggered):

Check for pin low, if low - terminate, no interrupt wait needed
Enable interrupt, check for low level again to ensure it did not change during interrupt enable. if it is low - disable interrupt and exit
Wait for interrupt
Disable interrupt and exit

How would you implement it?

The requirements are strange to begin with, maybe you need to fix your hardware first?

@0andriy the device deliberately works this way and initially oriented for user-space polling. This is an attempt to make things (hopefully) even faster within the kernel using interrupts. For now, there're no signs that kernel interrupts will be faster than user-space polling.

Linux is not an RTOS, there is no guarantee that IRQ handler will be fast enough. Still kernel tries to achieve that on all means. With the correct tuning the polling will be not much faster, but the resource consumption may be quite inefficient in the case of polling. I assume you poke GPIO controller registers from user space directly? If so, this is big no-no for multi-task multi-user general purpose OS.

This is clear. I do not expect immediate predictability of Linux in this sense, but I need specific overall performance which can be assessed. Polling is performed using ioctl. The kernel with irq endeavor is primarily being pursued to minimize CPU load and user space <-> kernel switching.

@Anonymous "I have checked involved CPU datasheet ..." - Do not conflate CPU with SoC. A CPU does not incorporate a "PIO controller". If you are confused about the capabilities of the SoC you're using, then it's time that you reveal what you are using instead of keeping it a mystery.

@sawdust added. now this info is really relevant. thanks.


it seems these flags can not be changed on the fly

Because interrupts, by convention, are generated by hardware and then detected by hardware, i.e. the interrupt controller attached to the CPU. What can be detected with interrupts is constrained by the HW.
In theory the HW configuration of the interrupt controller can be "changed on the fly", but it would be a time-consuming disruption that probably indicates an inapproprite design.

How would you implement it?

Seems like interrupting on IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_BOTH would work.
Instead of trying to obtain an interrupt for a specific level, you have to accept an interrupt that occurs on every change of state. A low state that changes to the high state creates a rising edge and an interrupt. A high state that changes to the low state creates a falling edge and an interrupt.
Your ISR in the kernel needs to check the state (high or low), and then perform the appropriate action based on the current state.

sometimes I need the read() to block until line gets low, and sometimes until it gets high

So the driver that services this read() would consult a binary flag that reflects the current state of the line. This flag compared with a blocking condition would determine what this request does next.
The state of the line is monitored by a driver that has an ISR which is invoked for any edge on that line/input (which means a change of state). The ISR would update the binary flag to reflect the current state of the line.
If the other driver has a read() request that is blocked because it is waiting for this change of state, then this ISR also signals that other driver that the wait condition has occurred.
To insure that the binary flag (that reflects the current state of the line) is not a critical region (i.e. subject to race conditions), it should be encapsulated and its value fetched only by calling a function. This function would handle the mutual exclusion for the variable shared with the ISR.

ADDENDUM

Driver needs to read the current state (value) of the GPIO set up as irq line - is it possible and how?

The pch_udc.c driver in mainline Linux kernel provides an example implementation that is very similar to what is previously described above.
In pch_vbus_gpio_init() a GPIO is initialized as a interrupt source that triggers an interrupt on both/any edges:
static int pch_vbus_gpio_init(struct pch_udc_dev *dev)
{
    ...
    /* Retrieve the GPIO line from the USB gadget device */
    gpiod = devm_gpiod_get_optional(d, NULL, GPIOD_IN);
    ...
    dev->vbus_gpio.port = gpiod;
    ...
    irq_num = gpiod_to_irq(gpiod);
    ...
        irq_set_irq_type(irq_num, IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_BOTH);
        err = request_irq(irq_num, pch_vbus_gpio_irq, 0,
            "vbus_detect", dev);
        ...
        }
    }

In pch_vbus_gpio_irq() this ISR for the GPIO pin performs a read of the pin state, and then schedules the appropriate follow-up work:
static irqreturn_t pch_vbus_gpio_irq(int irq, void *data)
{
    ...
    if (pch_vbus_gpio_get_value(dev))
        schedule_work(&dev->vbus_gpio.irq_work_rise);
    else
        schedule_work(&dev->vbus_gpio.irq_work_fall);

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

The function pch_vbus_gpio_get_value() is simply an encapsulation of the generic GPIO get value function:
static int pch_vbus_gpio_get_value(struct pch_udc_dev *dev)
{
    ...
        vbus = gpiod_get_value(dev->vbus_gpio.port) ? 1 : 0;
    ...
    return vbus;
}

Note that the GPIO pin state is not saved by the ISR (so that eliminates a possible critical region). The bottom-half routine that is scheduled can choose to save the value (e.g. in pch_vbus_gpio_work_fall()).

For your situation a function similar to pch_vbus_gpio_get_value() can be called in the initialization routine after the GPIO is initialized as a interrupt source, in order to assign a correct initial value to the binary flag that reflects the current state.
You seem overly concerned about this initialization of the flag value. When initializations are performed in a reasonable sequence, i.e. an interrupt handler is initialized well before any request from userspace is accepted, then there's no race condition that causes bogus values.


Edit 1: ...   PIO controller may simply not expose the current value if pin is configured as "functional pin", not as input or output.

You're probably misreading and/or misunderstanding what's in the SoC datasheet. That would be very goofy hardware if a GPIO pin used as an interrupt source could not also be read.

However it seems to be possible to change configuration of the interrupt function on the fly through the PIO registers.

Nobody said otherwise; you're really arguing with yourself.
But you're considering an ill-advised scheme.

ADDENDUM 2

Edit 1: ...   PIO controller may simply not expose the current value if pin is configured as "functional pin", not as input or output.

So you are not misreading or misunderstanding what's in the SoC datasheet. Seems like Allwinner SoCs have optimized (or economized depending on perspective) the pin control subsystem. In a conventional pin control subsystem (e.g. TI, Freescale/NXP, Atmel/Microchip) pin multiplexing only selects basic functionality (i.e. a peripheral connection or a GPIO), and then the GPIO pin direction and interrupt generation are controlled separately. Whereas the Allwinner forces a distinct choice of one of those three configurations in the multiplexing control.
Hence the Allwinner really doesn't have conventional GPIO pins (as expected by the Linux kernel). Rather a GP pin (i.e. not assigned to a peripheral) must either be multiplexed as an input or an output or an interrupt source. Then Allwinner chooses to restrict reading the pin input to only when the pin is multiplexed for input. In contrast, Atmel (e.g. AT91SAM9 and SAMA5 series of SoCs) allows reading the pin input regardless of pin configuration.

do you think it would be better to just perform request_irq with appropriate flags before polling, and then perform free_irq after receiving the interrupt?

Better than what?
Kernel routines such as request_irq() and free_irq() are intended for device driver initialization and then termination. These routines have high system overhead because they modify the hardware configuration and system resources.
Essentially you're asking an XY question.
Your solution for the Y problem is not really practical. You cannot always take a method of polling by userspace software, and somehow convert it to use hardware interrupts in the kernel. The hardware requires configuration. Those configurations should be performed well before any user operations are handled to avoid race conditions.
I only needed a few minutes to find a Linux device driver in the mainline source tree that matched the proposed implementation of using IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_BOTH.
I challenge you to find a driver in the mainline source tree that does anything similar to what you propose.

As a workaround to the Allwinner's restrictions, I would find a free pin, connect that pin to the interrupt pin, and multiplex that pin as an input so that it can be read.

Thanks, that's all great except one issue: it is required to know at least initial state of the irq line to then properly track its change. If I read pin before I set it up as an irq then its state may change between read and irq setup, and whole game will go wrong. After I set it up as irq I am no more able to read it. This is required to have this software flag to truly reflect the irq line state.

"except one issue" - Of course the binary flag that reflects the current state of the line has to be initialized. "After I set it up as irq I am no more able to read it" - According to whom/what? That would apparently invalidate my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818574/gpio-irq-falling-and-rising-edge-detection BTW referring to yourself (as if you are the computer, e.g. "I set it up as irq") instead of mentioning which piece of code can be confusing to others, especially if you've written a lot of routines/modules for a project.

"opening GPIO pin for level read is not possible because it is busy with interrupt" - "Open" is a userspace operation; you're trying to describe restrictions in userspace. But I wrote that the "ISR in the kernel needs to check the state". I specifically mentioned that this happens in a kernel driver, and not in userspace.  So when you claim that ""I set it up as irq ...", that is ambiguous. What routine is "I"? Is "I" the computer executing in kernel or user mode?

I see, you are correct, I mix two things in search for the way to implement what I need. I hope this will be clearer - "driver needs to read the current state (value) of the GPIO set up as irq line - is it possible and how?". If this question is answered, I will be able to implement the state machine within the driver.

Thank you very much for your efforts and help. I added table from the datasheet about reading the GPIO. If it would allow reading state of the pin configured as interrupt, it must state such explicitly. Otherwise this hardware is "goofy" or documentation is bad. I have additional question - do you think it would be better to just perform request_irq with appropriate flags before polling, and then perform free_irq after receiving the interrupt? This way there will be no need to read the pin at all - just set the correct level (low or high), and as soon as it is sensed - get interrupt.
